# Sequence $a_1=n, a_{k+1}=2a_k-[\sqrt{a_k} ]^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find all positive integers $n$ for which the sequence

$$a_1=n,  a_{k+1}=2a_k-[\sqrt{a_k} ]^2 $$ for all $k \ge 1,$ 
is periodic?

*Author: V. Yasinski*

Comment: What do you mean by the brakets?

Comment: [a] - the greatest integer that does not exceed a (exapmle, [3,1]=3; [-4,1]=-5)

Comment: You have $a_{k+1}\geq a_k$, so to get periodic it must get constant. $a_{k+1}=a_k$ iff $a_k$ is a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $n = m^2,\ m \in \mathbb N$, then $a_2 = 2m^2 - m^2 = m^2 = a_1$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb N,$ so $a_{k+1} = a_k$ and $a_k$ is periodic with period $1.$

Let's suppose that $a_k$ has form $m^2 + l,$ $m = \left[\sqrt{n}\right],\ l > 0.$ Then $a_{k+1} = m^2 + 2l > a_k.$ So if you start with $a_1$ which is not square of a natural number then $a_2 > a_1$ and $a_{k+1} \geq a_k$ $\forall k \in \mathbb N$. So there is no $k$ such that $a_k = a_1$ and the sequence is not periodic for $n$ that is not square of a natural number.